# Why is $C^5[a,b]$ infinite dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $V$ denote the vector space $C^5[a,b]$ over $R$.

How to show it is infinite dimensional?

I know that we can write:

$C^5[a,b]$ = { $f\in$ $C[a,b]$ : $5$th derivative exists and is continuous}

How to show that there does not exist a linearly independent subset of $V$ which spans V ?

Comment: Polynomials are in that vector space..

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1844631/269764

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Hint:

Note that $\mathbb{R}[x] \subset C^5([a,b],\mathbb{R})$ and that $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is not finite dimensional.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly functions $x^n$, $n=1,2,...$ are in your space. To prove that these functions are linearly independent consider the Wronskian.

Comment: Yes..I can see they are linearly independent..How does that imply anything?

Comment: That means that the space is inf. dim. A fin. dim. space cannot contain an infinite l.i. subset.